# file-notify-add-watch : get file path string

Tags: files, process, events

I would to do a specific action (create an org-mod link) when a new file appears in a given directory. For that I need to catch the event but also the path of the new file. I managed to use file-notify-add-watch function which is described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Notifications.html) and its work very well, but the output is an "event". How to get a string from this event ?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation you linked to states:

> When any event happens, Emacs will call the callback function passing it a single argument event, which is of the form
>
> ```
>      (descriptor action file [file1])
> ```

where

> file and file1 are the name of the file(s) whose event is being reported

So you could get the filename from `event` using `(third event)` (and/or `fourth` if multiple files changed).